# Different DataFrame plotting behaviour when using FigureCanvasQTAgg

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to create a plot of several data series that are contained in a pandas DataFrame. Let's use `df` as an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'1': [1,2,3], '2': [1,4,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

This code produces a simple line chart with two different data series:

[image: plot of two lines]

However, if I try and create this same plot in a PyQt widget using `FigureCanvasQTAgg`, I only get a single line. My code for the second example is a little more involved:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget, QSizePolicy, QApplication

class DisplayWidget( QWidget ):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super( DisplayWidget, self).__init__( parent )

        self.initUI()

        d = {'1': [1,2,3], '2': [1,4,9]}        
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(d)
        self.canvas.plot_data_frame(self.df)

    def initUI(self):

        self.canvas = PlotCanvas(self)

class PlotCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.axes.hold(False)

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                   QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                   QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)


    def plot_data_frame( self, df, **kwargs ):
        df.plot( ax = self.axes, **kwargs )
        self.draw()        

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication( [] )
    widget = DisplayWidget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

When I run this code, the output looks like this:

[image: plot of one line]

If anyone can shed any light on this, it would be hugely appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
self.axes.hold(False)
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you know how I could then remove these series to be left with a blank plot? I tried `self.axes.cla()` but this does nothing...

Comment: call `self.axes.cla()` then `self.fig.canvas.draw()`